# How many level order BST sequences are possible given a preOrder and inOrder sequence?

Tags: algorithm, binary-tree, binary-search-tree, inorder, preorder

When I am trying to print level Order of BST, this question prompted me.

Here is a

```
Pre-Order Sequence: 4, 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8
In_order Sequence : 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8
```

A level order sequence for a BST with above `pre_order` and `In_order` is
`[4, 2, 6, 1, 3, 5, 7, 8]`

However, for the same Pre-order an In-order sequence this level order sequence seems possible. `[4, 1, 5, 2, 6, 3, 7, 8]`. I don't know how. I am trying to figure this out.

I am unable to construct BST in paper (drawing) that satisfies all the pre_order, In-order and level order sequences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have in-order traversal together with one of pre/post-order, that is enough to reconstruct a binary tree. Moreover, in case of BST (binary **search** tree), post-order or pre-order alone is sufficient.

In your case, reconstructing a BST from pre-order `4, 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8` gives the following BST:

```
     4
   /   \
  1     5
   \     \
    2     6
     \     \
      3     7
             \
              8
```

which gives, again unique, level-order traversal `[4,1,5,2,6,3,7,8]`.

See also:

- [Reconstructing binary trees from tree traversals](http://www.cmi.ac.in/~madhavan/courses/programming06/lecture12-21sep2006.txt)

Comment: my doubt is for the above given preOrder and Inorder, why two level order sequences are possible?

Comment: your first level order is wrong.means if you construct tree from given preorder & in order you will get unique tree & level order for that tree will  be [4, 1, 5, 2, 6, 3, 7, 8]  not  [4, 2, 6, 1, 3, 5, 7, 8]

Answer (score 1):

Following combination will generate unique binary tree(which can be BST).

```
Inorder and Preorder.
Inorder and Postorder.
Inorder and Level-order.
```

So in your case inorder & pre order are given which will generate unique binary tree which is BST in your case so level order will be unique for that tree.

```
Pre-Order Sequence: 4, 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8
In_order Sequence : 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8
```

**SO tree will be**

```
level 0- 4
level 1- 1,5
level 2- 2,6
level 3- 3,7
level 4- 8
```

Level order is

> 4,1,5,2,6,3,7,8

in sort there will always unique level order traversal

Comment: look at this. I have some related question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31020267/converting-sorted-linked-list-to-balanced-binarytree-not-returning-correctly